# Might Google log every website I visit using Chrome?

Tags: privacy, dns, google, chrome

I wanted to start using Chrome for quite some time now, but I really don't want to tell Google about whatever sites I visit. 
So I was wondering if Chrome sends any data to Google telling them what I'm doing etc.
I'm specifically wondering if the latest versions of Chrome are using Google's DNS servers to resolve any domain I'm visiting because then they would know about every single site that I'm visiting on the Internet, even if I blocked Google Analytics etc.

I'm also thinking about the navigation bar which might send every character I type in real time to Google to give me search suggestions before even knowing that I was just going to enter a URL instead of a search.

In case you confirm my suspicion, could I do something about all this?

Comment: Using Google's DNS tells them which domains you visit. And using Chrome gives them complete access to your computer at your user account's privilege level. It's safe to say that Google can and will log everything you do in Chrome (as their business model is to violate everyone's privacy) and can even do much more if they wanted to.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Can is not the same as will. Technically, every program on your computer *could* be logging all your keystrokes and sending them back to whatever company wrote them. That doesn't mean they are, and it would be presumptuous to say that they are without specific evidence indicating so.

Comment: @Ajedi32 but it depends on the business model of the company behind the software. Given that Google's main source of revenue is from selling user's personal data and violating everyone's privacy wherever possible, I think there are good reasons to be worried.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I don't mean to be rude, but that sounds an awful lot like FUD. Google's main source of revenue is serving ads to users. They don't sell user data to anyone. And I honestly don't see how "violating everyone's privacy wherever possible" would generate any revenue.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I realize you probably don't agree with Google's business practices, but as pointed out in Chrome's privacy notice linked in the answers below, Google claims "If you use Chrome to access other Google services, such as using the search engine on the Google homepage or checking Gmail, the fact that you are using Chrome does not cause Google to receive any special or additional personally identifying information about you." Unless you have evidence to the contrary, I don't really see what your objection is.

Comment: @Ajedi32 a privacy policy or lawsuit doesn't magically make someone "unsee" something they weren't intended to see, and I would be extremely uncomfortable knowing a company specialized in advertising/analytics has complete access to my computer.

Comment: @Ajedi32 well yes, they don't sell the data because it's just so much more profitable to keep it for themselves and use it only for their products (analytics, ads, etc). By violating everyone's privacy everywhere, I mean that every single time they have the opportunity to collect data for their analytics they'll do it, which then can be used to better target ads (though it will never work on me, I suppose it's pretty effective at getting non-tech-savvy people to buy stuff).

Comment: @AndréDaniel If none of my personal information is ever shared with any living being who's not me, how can that be a "violation" of my privacy? Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22348/discussion-between-ajedi32-and-andre-daniel)

Comment: If anyone is going to have my raw data, I want it with Google. It is their economic interest to keep it secure. I appreciate their models transforming that data into suggestions for things I might be interested in, at no cost to me. Fair deal imo, but maybe I am missing the unforeseen. FWIW Google Fi's included mobile VPN has anonymous authentication, so they aren't being overly greedy with my data.

Comment: @Ajedi32 it is more than just ads that recommend a paid product. For example, content recommendations on Google TV based on other people with similar likes and interests. Ethically, I am totally fine with a bot/model combing through what I do. I consider myself "tech-savy" as well :P which is why I upvote content I like because I continue to get good recommendations

Answer (score 5):

Read Google Chrome's privacy policy [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/)

Navigational errors caused are resolved automatically through Google servers. You can disable them in the Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy. In fact, you may disable all checkboxes in Privacy section in order to not allow contacting Google every time you search something.

You can also block cookies from Google in the Content Settings, disable auto-translation, Auto-fill and password manager. And of course, disable all extensions, themes and apps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Google gives you exceptional "control" over your privacy, but the fact is most users will never find out about these features.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is sending the information to Google but It uses your computer's dns server.

In Google you even have an ad ID correlated with you. This way they get to know your interests and give you according advertisements. However, I think that with incognito mode it doesn't send anything, because that's the point of it.

EDIT: [This part is about incognito] So, basicly, I'm not sure what exactly it is sending, but it is sending loads of packets to google each time you open a web site. So it is propably sending information about where you go. But it doesn't affect your ad ID, so it's propably not stored in correlation with you.

To the dns part, it uses your computers standard dns server.

Everything based on wireshark digging.

**Answer to your question:** yes it might be logging it. If you want sure privacy, don't use Google.

Comment: Do you have any refs that back up your statement on incognito mode?

Comment: and also for the DNS thing?

Comment: Well, at least that it doesn't account for the ad ID

Comment: Gonna check it out later

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm rather hesitant to vote on this since this answer is entirely speculation. If you actually observe this in wireshark, you should tell what exactly you're observing. Did you just notice that there is traffic, or did you actually observe what's in the traffic? Why do you have so many "probably"s in your answer?

Comment: Well, I thought I made it clear, I've seen lots of tcp traffic being sent to google everytime you open any website, incognito or not, although I didn't observe what it is exactly. However, the dns traffic goes by the standard route defined in your pc, as everytime you open a website, the dns traffic goes there, also observed.

Comment: @Cube It seems to me that Google [spells out pretty clearly](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/) under what conditions Chrome will contact Google's servers. Your assumption that "yes, they're *probably* maintaining a log of every site you visit" is completely incorrect, according to that page.

Comment: @Cube If you want to argue that they're lying, I think it would be a good idea to provide stronger evidence than "probably". Have you tried disabling all the options in chrome://settings/search#Privacy to see if that affects the data that gets sent to Google?

Comment: Actually, I think I never really accused them of lying. They may be logging it without logging who went on the site. Just that someone did it. Also, the question was if Google might log it. And yes, it might, even if it is little propable.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that many, many web sites are logging your traffic using the same tools, and that other players in the market have the ability to track you across different web properties. If you are that concerned about it, download the Ghostery plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij.

Comment: What is happening when you visit a site incognito is your cache/cookies are clean as if you just installed chrome and haven't logged in. So, they create a new ID for you and see if they can correlate it back to your primary ID. Say you opened incognito on the same IP address seconds later, doesn't take a genius to correlate that one.